# Width of image description

Tags: html, css

I have an article, containing an image with description. The discription should not be longer than the image.
The width of the image may differ, so I can't set the class .article-image to a fixed width (what would solve the problem).

```css
article {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.leadtext {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.article-image img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.article-image>div {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="leadtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</div>
  <div>
    <div class="article-image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr | &copy; author</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</article>
```

http://codepen.io/DaFunkyAlex/pen/mWMVdz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a bit unconventional, a pure css solution exsists.
It leverages `display:table` to calculate the width of the cells.

The Image can have a dynamic size. 
The caption will grow to the size of the Image and no further, It will start occupying new lines if necessary.

On `.article-image` add: `display:table;`.
On `.article-image > div` add `display: table-caption;` and `caption-side: bottom;`

```css
article {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.leadtext {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.article-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  display: table;
}

.article-image img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.article-image > div {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="leadtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</div>
  <div>
    <div class="article-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr | &copy; author</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3):

**It's called `<figure>` with `<figurecaption>`**

You can add a caption to an Image by putting it inside a `<figure>` tag and adding the `<figcaption>`, which can then include `<p>` tags, etc..
The `<figure>` tag is used to section content. Figures can also be used to display code snippets distinguished from other content.

```css
/* Should you want to center the caption:
figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
figure img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}*/
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/N7dX8.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
  <figcaption>A doge above a very long text with Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

According to @Lars answer: `display: table-caption` setted on caption is a solution without assuming anything.

**Original**

I think there is no way to do it, without counting in JS or assumption size.
In my opinion, the best solution would be, to assume *number of lines in description*

If you know how many lines your description will have, you can set fixed (with em) padding for it. And *position:absolute* on description paragraph.

[fixed 2 lines example](http://codepen.io/kornel-dylski/pen/vxJGLY)

```
.article-image {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 2em;  
}

.article-image > div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

It will not work for narrow images, because description will be to narrow and will have many lines. But I think you dont need 1 word per 1 line.

Comment: A pure css solution is definitely possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code......

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.leadtext {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.article-image img {
  display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width:140px;
}

.article-image>div {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="leadtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</div>
  <div>
    <figure class="article-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
      <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consetetur sadipscing elitr | &copy; author</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis ipsum, sed sit rerum aut cum ducimus odio dignissimos! Obcaecati quaerat, provident fugiat
      assumenda inventore dolore laudantium praesentium minima nulla aperiam! Ea nihil laudantium delectus eius iusto voluptatibus beatae pariatur, ducimus, ratione voluptatem. Unde perferendis laboriosam neque, soluta ducimus, maiores. Necessitatibus
      nihil, eaque harum temporibus qui autem earum beatae placeat numquam ab possimus dolores voluptatum fugiat expedita maxime consectetur est veniam esse minima odio saepe, doloremque dolorum repudiandae eum. Obcaecati possimus nostrum, eveniet culpa,
      ullam neque omnis adipisci magni consectetur esse accusantium suscipit amet repudiandae eos assumenda, iste blanditiis, aperiam aut!</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Moreover you can use `text-align` property !

Comment: You have set manualy <br> in your code. It will break if you increase font-size or change description to longer

Comment: Set Maximum width with proportional to image will be fix up this problem!

Comment: you set the max-width of figcaption to 140px. Actually I don't know the width of the image.

Comment: In your code you you use a place holder image width and height 100px and I use placeholder image width and height 140px ,So I keep **figcaption** width and height same as my picture width to keep caption text same alignment and used **text-align:center**  I hope you will accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your div does not know image width. You can however do a simple javascript calculation to achieve what you want:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.article-image');
for(i = 0;i<divs.length;i++) {
  var imgW = divs[i].querySelector('img').width;
  divs[i].querySelector('div').style.width = imgW+'px';
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrXbJJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it can't be done just by css if you don't have an explict image size.
I'd suggest a bit of js:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".article-image"),
    i = 0, ii = images.length;
for(i; i<ii; i++){
  images[i].style.width = images[i].querySelector("img").clientWidth + "px";
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpvxON

Comment: A pure CSS solution is definitely possible, see my answer.

Comment: Use moar jQuery

Answer (score -1):

an alternative is to use img tag in css

```css
article {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img{
  width: 350px;
}

.leadtext {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.article-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.article-image img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.article-image > div {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="leadtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</div>
  <div>
    <div class="article-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr | &copy; author</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add width to the div where both are

```
.article-image {
  width:100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```